# powershell pass command line arguments

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

Here is my code :

```
$script={
 Write-Host "Num Args:" $args.Length;
  Write-Host $args[0]   
}

Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock $script
```

When I run

```
  powershell.exe .\test.ps1 one two three
```

I got

```
Num Args: 0
```

I thought I would get

```
Num Args: 3
One
```

Something am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually have two scopes there. The script level and the script block level. `$args.Length` and `$args[0]` will have what you are expecting at the `Invoke-Command` level. Inside the script block there is another scope for `$args`. To get the args from the command line all the way into the script block you'll need to re-pass them from `Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $args`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the arguments to the scriptblock:

```
Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $args
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare named parameters explicitly. For example:

`param([switch]$someBoolSwitch=$false, [String]$nameOfSomething="some default string")`

This allows you to pass in named arguments to your script, like the following example:

`.\<nameOfScript.ps1> -someBoolSwitch -nameOfSomething "Slayer Roolz!"`

and if you omitted `-nameOfSomething "Slayer Roolz!"`, then `$nameOfSomething` would simply default to `"some default sting"`. Similarly, `$someBoolSwitch` defaults to `$false` unless otherwise defined.

This method has the benefit of allowing you as the developer to decide which parameters are necessary and which ones can be omitted or defaulted. Furthermore, it allows the user to enter arguments in any order they like, since they're named and not positional.

One drawback to having named parameters as opposed to positional parameters is that the command-line invocation can become quite large since the user has to type in each parameter name.